# MongoDb group in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm new in mongoDB and I don't know how to start. I want to group some documents from my db by a common value. Here I leave an axample:

```
{_id: 1, tag1: 1; tag2: 2}
{_id: 2, tag1: 3; tag2: 4}
{_id: 3, tag1: 2; tag2: 5}
{_id: 4, tag1: 1; tag2: 6}
{_id: 5, tag1: 1; tag2: 7}
```

As you can see I have some values in common in tag1; I want to group the thing like:

```
{_id: "valueoftag1", values:{_id: 1, tag2: 2}, {_id: 4, tag2: 6}, {_id: 5, tag2:7}}
```

more or less. 
How can I structure my code in Java?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I've tried cycling into the collection with the aggregate function and then some match and group but I can't get what I want

Comment: Can you post your code to point your in correct direction?

Comment: `Consumer<Document> printBlock = new Consumer<Document>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Document document) {
                System.out.println(document.toJson());
            }
        };

        mongoCollection.aggregate(
                Arrays.asList(
                        Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("tag1", "1")),
                        Aggregates.group("tag1", I dont know what to put here)
                )
        ).forEach(printBlock);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$tag1",
      values: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$_id",
          tag2: "$tag2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

---

### MongoDB Driver

```
mongoCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
    new Document("$group", new Document("_id", "$tag1")
      .append("values", new Document("$push", new Document("_id", "$_id").append("tag2", "$tag2"))))));
```

### Spring Data

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    new AggregationOperation() {
        @Override
        public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
            return new Document("$group", new Document("_id", "$tag1")
                        .append("values", new Document("$push", new Document("_id", "$_id").append("tag2", "$tag2"))));
        }
    };
);
```

Comment: It seems that I can't run this in java

Comment: And the thing is that I also have something like a hundred tags in each document so I can't write them down by hand

Comment: @subDir99 This code is for Spring Data. Wait a sec for Java code